# Xephyr -ac dangerously?

Tags: x11, x-server, xephyr

Classic command to run Xephyr:

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 800x600 :1
```

As far as I understand, the **-ac** key is an analogue of xhost +, and this is a vulnerability, because almost everyone can access the monitor, mouse, keyboard.

How can this be fixed in the Xephyr example?

*UPD:* **mosvy** thank you very much for the very detailed answer! Indeed, even without “**ac**” access is open to all. Your [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505480/308316) opened my eyes to xorg and ssh from a security point of view. Regular Xorg server on my LiveCD/USB really through -auth:

```
$ pgrep -ai Xorg
551 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the `-auth auth-file` option, `Xephyr :1` already allows anybody from the same host to connect to it, even without the `-ac` option. Try this:

```
hinz$ Xephyr :1 &
```

then, as another user

```
kunz$ xclock -display :1
```

This also applies to *any* X server, not just `Xephyr`; if you look at your regular `Xorg` server, you will see that the `-auth` option is passed explicitly:

```
$ pgrep -ai Xorg
2347 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

According to the `Xserver(1)` manpage (emphasis mine):

> The X server also uses a host-based access control  list  for  deciding
>          whether  or  not to accept connections from clients on a particular machine.  **If no other authorization mechanism is being  used**,  this  list
>          initially  consists  of the **host on which the server is running** as well
>          as any machines listed in the file `/etc/Xn.hosts`

As already mentioned in another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505480/308316), some Xorg servers (eg. Xwayland) don't support any authenticating mechanism beyond checking who opened the unix socket via `getsockopt(SO_PEERCRED)` -- the "localuser & localgroup server interpreted access type" from `Xsecurity(7)`; also, some distros like Debian [gapped](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/xorg/-/commit/9b1d91483680a3e9282bffb0aca4a08bd533e36e) the regular Xorg server via `xhost +si:localuser:$(id -un)` from an xsession script. Since a socket fd can be passed around and a client could be proxied by programs like `xscope`, that's a VERY foolish thing to do.

#### What to do

If you want to prevent other users from connecting to your X server, you have to use some form of authentication.

Create an authorization file, pass it via the `-auth` option to the X server, and then let the client use the same when connecting to the server.

```
   # create a MIT-COOKIE authfile
$ xauth -f ~/.xauth-junk add :1 . "$(hexdump -n 16 -e '4/4 "%08x"' /dev/urandom)"
xauth:  file /home2/ahq/.xauth-junk does not exist # it will be created

$ Xephyr :1 -auth ~/.xauth-junk &
```

Then either merge it in your usual `$XAUTHORITY` file (`~/.Xauthority` if not overridden in the environment)

```
$ xauth merge - < ~/.xauth-junk
$ xclock -display :1
```

Or pass it explicitly in the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable:

```
$ XAUTHORITY=~/.xauth-junk xclock -display :1
```

You can check it the `-auth` option really had any effect by trying to connect with a bogus auth file:

```
$ XAUTHORITY=/dev/null xdpyinfo -display :1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo OOPS, anybody can connect!
$
```

Comment: Tell me please how to determine whether "-auth" is applied or not? I want to create 2 users: offline and online, so that I can constantly work from under offline, and run Firefox from under a user online. I execute the command `Xephyr :1 -auth ~/.xauth-junk &`, but if there is no .xauth-junk file, it still creates a window to which anyone can connect.

Comment: Is there a way to check if `-auth` is loaded or not? If I execute the code: `Xephyr :1 -auth ~/.xauth-junk &` but there is no file .xauth-junk, in any case a window will open, and anyone can connect to it.

Comment: In any case, a new window opens, and if the file was not read _(the file is missing, rights are not allowed, the owner of the file does not match, etc.)_, anyone can connect as if there was no parameter `-auth`

Comment: @My5555 Yes, it's bad that the X server doesn't warn about inexistent `-auth` file. I don't know of any special way to check, but you could try running some client with a bogus authority file and see if it succeeds: `XAUTHORITY=/dev/null xdpyinfo -display :1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo OOPS, anybody
 can connect` or `XAUTHORITY=/dev/null DISPLAY=:1 xhost >/dev/null 2>&1 && ...`.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked answer, if you run that on Xwayland or on the main Xorg server in Debian, it will succeed; that's because they configured it to authenticate the clients by checking who opened the socket via `getsockopt(SO_PEERCRED)` (configured via eg. `xhost +si:localuser:username` -- see the `Xsecurity(7)` manpage (and `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/35x11-common_xhost-local` on any Debian machine). That's very bad, and I always disable it on `Xorg`, but that's not possible on Xwayland, because it's the only auth mechanism that Xwayland supports.

Comment: I apologize for being off topic. Tell me please how to open the application in full screen in Xephyr? An open application in Xephyr has a fixed size and does not respond to F11. I tried different keys, but on my Debian system the application in Xephyr always opens with a fixed size, everything else is black

Comment: @My5555 `Xephyr :1 -resizeable` and using my wm's keybinding to make a window full screen works for me. And the resolution appears correctly in `Xrandr`.

Comment: A window created by Xephyr itself becomes full-screen, but the content remains fixed.

Comment: Are you using a window-manager _inside_ Xephyr? If no, use one. Otherwise apps like firefox, chromium, etc won't run properly -- they depend on a wm, unfortunately. And not only for resizing; drop menus won't open, input boxes won't focus, etc.