# Xephyr cannot open host display. Is DISPLAY set?

Tags: x11, tty

I' try to play with Xephyr under tty:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 Xephyr -ac -screen 800x600 -host-cursor

Xephyr cannot open host display. Is DISPLAY set?
```

As u can see, `DISPLAY` has been set, but Xephyr still cannot see it.

Comment: `DISPLAY` cannot be just anything. For `:0` there should be a `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` unix socket (or an `@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` abstract unix socket on Linux) __and__ an X11 server listening on it. And `DISPLAY` is not always `:0`. On some distros, it's something like `:8` or similar. When forwarded via ssh, it's `localhost:10.0`.

Comment: Also, why are you using `-ac`? It's [pointless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571152/308316). Is that copied from somewhere else? Where from?

Comment: You have to **export** DISPLAY=:0; most programs get it from their environment. IIRC, some systems need 0.0. The generic format is 'hostname:workstation.screen'

Comment: @Paul_Pedant no, `FOO=bar cmd` will _export_ `FOO` in the environment of `cmd`, just try with `FOO=bar printenv FOO`. And `:0` is enough, no need of `:0.0`.

Comment: @mosvy. Actually, Xephyr documentation specifically shows (a) `export DISPLAY=:1.0`, and (b) Display is an arg:: `Xephyr -ac -screen 1024x768 -br -reset -terminate 2> /dev/null :1 &`. It's an X-on-X server and apparently abhors :0. `If we do not change it, Xephyr won't get any data forwarded to it.`

Comment: `Xephyr` is a _nested_ X server. You're mixing up the display `Xephyr` runs on with the one it creates for other X11 clients to run on. And no, there's no need of `.0`, screen 0 is the default anyway (and the only one in 99.99% of cases).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant if the OP doesn't add a `:1` or `:7` (or whatever free display name) to their command, as in `DISPLAY=:0 Xephyr :1 -screen 800x600 -host-cursor`, then `Xephyr` will die with an error like `Another server is already active for display :0`. But they haven't reached that point yet. Their `Xephyr` has yet to connect to the display it should run in.

Comment: @mosvy, And, although it apparently got passed the X server DISPLAY, it says it is unset. So presumably we can't diagnose the fault from the information provided. Maybe there is a log, or a diagnostic mode, or a better manual, or a bug-fix.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The same error happens when it cannot open the display unix socket. Try with `DISPLAY=:19 Xephyr :1` or (on Linux) `unshare -Urnm sh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/junk; mount -B /tmp/junk /tmp/.X11-unix; Xephyr :1'` (which runs in a namespace where it doesn't have access to `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` or `@ /tmp/.X11-unix/X0`. It's nothing special; the error has been that obtuse since 40 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

Xephir runs on *X11*. If you are running on a tty (i.e., virtual console on Linux, no graphics), there is no X server to connect to. Ditto if you are running Wayland on your display server, no X server around.